# android: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe LG

Tags: android, socketexception, broken-pipe, lg

I'm developing an application for Android 2.2 and LG Black devices.
When I run the application on my LG device I get the following SocketException, which is never happen on other devices!

```
Broken pipe
  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.writeSocketImpl(Native Method)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.write(OSNetworkSystem.java:723)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:578)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:59)
```

How It can be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a bit more context, such as the details of what sort of socket it is that is breaking and under what conditions.

Answer (score 6):

your side-A
the other end-B

when A getting data from B,B closed->SocketException: Broken pipe

Comment: U have to make sure the Code logic correct that when A getting data,B can't close.

Comment: Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459325/android-client-to-net-server-side-results-in-broken-pipe
I am a newbie in this part of programming. Kindly help if you can.